# Use SELECT result as COLUMN name in other SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to use the result of a select as a string to concatenate with another string in column name in other select?

Example:

```
SELECT brand 
FROM articles a 
WHERE a.id='12345678'
```

Result:  `BRAND_A`

I now want to concatenate `_PRICE` to `BRAND_A`...

```
SELECT (
        SELECT brand
        FROM articles a
        WHERE a.id = '12345678'
        ) + "_PRICE"
FROM prices p
WHERE p.id = '12345678'
```

...to actually retrieve:

```
SELECT BRAND_A_PRICE
FROM prices p
WHERE p.id = '12345678'
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: It is possible with dynamic sql query

Comment: I have a list of articles from different brands and each brand has a different discount per client

Comment: Dynamic SQL isn't strictly needed here, though it does sound like your database could be restructured.

Comment: What does your tables look like? How are they related? Maybe a join or apply could do what you want.

Comment: There are no relations between the tables. @davidg answer solved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need dynamic SQL to do this (and dynamic SQL should be avoided if at all possible). Instead you can use a CASE statement. You can do this with a single statement but I've split it out for display purposes:

```
DECLARE @brand VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT brand FROM articles a WHERE a.id='12345678')

SELECT CASE @brand
           WHEN 'BRAND_A' THEN BRAND_A_PRICE
           WHEN 'BRAND_B' THEN BRAND_B_PRICE
           WHEN 'BRAND_C' THEN BRAND_C_PRICE
           ELSE 0 END AS PRICE
FROM prices
WHERE id='12345678'
```

Comment: @Pedro And you'll have to remember to update this when a new BRAND is added to your table. As David commented you should seriously consider restructuring your DB because this is gonna get you in trouble in the long run.

Comment: Agreed....there really should be some sort of relational table to sit between these, because it's going to become a headache at best if/when there ends up being 100+ brands sitting in that case statement...

Comment: @JanDoggen Yes i know, but i can't restruct the DB, i'm using a DB that is already in production and is used by another app. And I have only 13 brands.. So it's easy to update.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need a `Dynamic SQL query`.

First store the `Brand` for the particular `ID` in a **variable** then use that variable in `Dynamic Query` appended with the `_PRICE` to get the result.

```
DECLARE @sql   NVARCHAR(max),
        @brand VARCHAR(500)

DECLARE @sql   NVARCHAR(max),
        @brand VARCHAR(500)

SELECT @brand = brand
FROM   articles a
WHERE  a.id = '12345678'

SET @sql ='SELECT ' + @brand + '_PRICE FROM prices p WHERE p.id=''12345678'''

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: but if i have a list of articles with diferent brands? should i do a query for each article?

Comment: @PedroLoureiro Nope that wont be a efficient way of doing it. But it will work